# Microsoft Visual Studio not Autocompleting Like in Tutorial

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I am new and trying to follow a tutorial to make a game.

Tutorial as follows:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OR0e-1UBEOU

At the 53:11 mark, he begins typing OnMouseDown and it calls the relevant code.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community, and copying exactly what he does not call out the intellisense.

I've went into Tools > Options > Intellicode and enabled everything but it doesn't work.

Would anyone be able to give this newbie a hand?

Comment: Add extensions..

Comment: C# intellisense should work out the box in Visual Studio (no extensions needed)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have installed `Game development with Unity` workload in Visual Studio Installer > Modify > Workloads.

[image]

Besides, check whether the default configuration has been set(details here: [Configure Unity to use Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?pivots=windows#configure-unity-to-use-visual-studio)).

Other document to refer to: [Intellisense for Unity API Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/using-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?pivots=windows#intellisense-for-unity-api-messages).

Answer (score 0):

Is your class inheriting from MonoBehaviour? You should have this at the top where you declare your class

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto => Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> C/C++ >> Advanced >>

->Make sure **Responsive code completion** is selected
->Set **Default IntelliSense completion Mode** accordingly

Comment: Not sure that OP is using C or C++. Maybe you should adapt your answer to address the **C#** settings.

Comment: The game link he mentioned and the timepoint he provided in YT video, it was in unity and using C#. Does not that mean he was addressing C# settings?